# How to set up Travis to build Arduino/Spark/Teensy library

Tags: c, makefile, travis-ci, avr-gcc

I have a few Github OSS hosted libraries aimed at running on multiple MCUs and I wish to set up Travis in order to have them built and tested (if possible) automatically.
I have run multiple searches and found a couple o different approaches, but none seems satisfying.

- One option seems to be using [inotool](http://inotool.org/), but while it seems working nicely for complete firmwares, I was unable to set it up in order to build a library
- Another option suggests the use of plain **Makefile**, but I'm struggling to have it working properly

I believe there should be a simple solution and I'm here asking for help and knowledge share.

One of the projects I'm going to apply the solution is going to be https://github.com/rlogiacco/MicroDebug, where you can find all my failing tries in the recent history changes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently Adafruit has got a solution published [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/continuous-integration-arduino-and-you/testing-your-project) which I expanded a bit further on the project I was pointing in my question.

You can get a full working example [travis configuration file](https://github.com/rlogiacco/MicroDebug/blob/master/.travis.yml) on my [MicroDebug](https://github.com/rlogiacco/MicroDebug) project.

Answer (score 0):

This worked great for me. One suggested change:

I made a variable in what is essentially going to be executed as a bash script. The top of my script looks like this

```
language: c

before_install:
  - ARD_VER="1.8.0"
  - "/sbin/start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile /tmp/custom_xvfb_1.pid --make-pidfile --background --exec /usr/bin/Xvfb -- :1 -ac -screen 0 1280x1024x16"
  - sleep 5
  - export DISPLAY=:1.0
  - echo "Downloading version $ARD_VER of the Arduino IDE..."
  - wget http://downloads.arduino.cc/arduino-$ARD_VER-linux64.tar.xz
  - echo "Extracting the Arduino IDE..."
  - tar xf arduino-$ARD_VER-linux64.tar.xz
  - echo "Moving Arduino IDE..."
  - sudo mv arduino-$ARD_VER /usr/local/share/arduino
  - echo "Linking Arduino IDE..."
  - sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/arduino/arduino /usr/local/bin/arduino
  - echo "Removing Arduino IDE ver $ARD_VER tar that was downloaded..."
  - rm arduino-$ARD_VER-linux64.tar.xz
install:
# ....the rest of the .travis.yml file goes below here...
```

So, this way, I can simply modify the Arduino IDE version number put into the `ARD_VER` variable and I can then test with the most recent version of Arduino! Yay!

Kind of a simple/stupid addition, but I thought it was worth mentioning.

Cheers!